# Proper way of setting up static IP settings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ip

When I am at home, I have no problem setting a static IP address for my VM running on virtualbox this way:

[image]

I'm able to SSH into it and ping it from the host machine.

However, at work, when I try to do the same exact thing I am unable to ping or SSH into it using the host machine.

I've also changed the `interfaces` file to this:

[image]

And still having the same result.

I've also tried this:

[image]

I've rebooted. I'm using bridged adapter.

here's the output of `route`:

[image]

output of `ifconfig -a`:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: it may not be anything on your end but switch port settings. have you attempted to contact your IT department? also it looks like your settings are placing the machine directly on your hosts network. is your networking set to Bridged? if you are using NAT, your configuration will not work as it stands now.

Comment: . I'm using bridged adapter.

Comment: Can you ping from the machine out to the network?  If so, maybe the device is running a firewall preventing ping and SSH responses.

Comment: @JimG. no i cannot

Comment: whats the output of 'route'? how about 'ifconfig -a'. what is your eth0 interface used for?

Comment: @FrankThomas ive added the output of route and ifconfig -a